# Wrong mount point for internal SSD

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, ssd

I am having a problem with mounting an internal SSD. For some reason The mounting point is chosen as `/media/user/Data` instead of, as specified in `/etc/fstab`, `/mnt/Data`. The according line in `/etc/fstab` goes as follows:

```
UUID="064ced5e-19c1-43d1-876f-3de0c115b65e"     /mnt/Data       ext4    users,noauto,exec,rw,async,dev  0       0
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit.

(edit:)

Here goes the complete fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=9cf86df3-3d02-45d7-8078-d6ff5fc83ea6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=5AC7-594F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdc5 during installation
UUID=5460f609-5245-417a-833a-271c533db97a none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID="064ced5e-19c1-43d1-876f-3de0c115b65e"     /mnt/Data      ext4    users,noauto,exec,rw,async,dev  0       0
```

Comment: Are you *sure* there is nothing else in your /etc/fstab that matches that partition on the SSD? Please dobule-check. The most likely explanation would seem to be an additional fstab entry, perhaps using some other type of device identifier.

Comment: I am fairly certain that there is nothing else. The partition is `/dev/sdb1`. There are other partitions that I am mounting, yet they are on ̀`dev/sdc`. I added the complete file to my question.

Comment: Um... **the two don't match.**

Comment: well silly me, I'm sorry I changed it because for example my VM needs it as a shared drive, which is annoying to change all the time. Also I might have to add that sometimes it does actually mount to `mnt/Data` when it is specified to that mounting point.

Comment: It seems that it indeed was the `noauto` setting that messed it all up. Although when setting it to `auto` the device was not able to be mounted at all. When completely left out, however, it seems like it works. I rebooted the computer twice, both times the device was mounted correctly at startup.

Comment: You'll probably want to turn that into an answer (there is a grace period of couple of hours when you can't).

Comment: @peterph since the problem did not turn up every time I rebooted the machine I decided to wait before doing so and unfortunately the problem has reappeared...

Comment: Could it possibly be the quotes around the UUID in the `/etc/fstab` entry?

Comment: what an easy answer, @peterph, how did I not spot that. I rebooted three times and it worked every single time so far. I'm rather convinced that this is the solution, so if you would post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the simplicity of the `/etc/fstab` parser I would expect, removing the quotes around the UUID in the affected entry might help that is, use

```
UUID=064ced5e-19c1-43d1-876f-3de0c115b65e    /mnt/Data    ...
```

instead of

```
UUID="064ced5e-19c1-43d1-876f-3de0c115b65e"  /mnt/Data    ...
```